# Comparison of the two variables

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to compare two variables like:

```
$user_role = $user_data->roles;
$post_role = get_field('choose_user_role', $child->ID);
```

They have:

```
Array([0] => top_manager [1] => manager)
```

I try use

`$intersection = array_intersect($post_role, $user_role);`

but have error:

> Warning: array_intersect(): Argument #1 is not an array

Comment: what's the var_dump of $post_role?

Comment: What prints  on  print_r($user_role) and print_r($post_role )

Comment: Use $user_role[] = $user_data->roles;

Comment: update your question with $user_data

Comment: `array (size=3)
  0 => string 'top_manager' (length=11)
  1 => string 'manager' (length=7)
  2 => string '' (length=0)`
and
`array (size=1)
  0 => string 'administrator' (length=13)`

Comment: You have to convert you first parameter in array (probably you get a string), so simply use: `array_intersect(array($post_role), $user_role);`